# Can't get the numeric value from HTML using parseInt or Number in my js function

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to complete this simple html page for a friend's project, the goal is to get 2 user entries, minutes and seconds, that will be compared to the data already in the table and if the minutes and seconds entered are greater than  one of the time in the table, it will be replaced by the entry.
I've never worked with js except to make some simple prompt or alert so I don't know what I'm supposed to do.
Here is the html, js and css :

```js
function timeEntry() {
  var min1 = Number(document.getElementById('firstTimeMin'));
  var sec1 = Number(document.getElementById('firstTimeSec'));
  var min2 = Number(document.getElementById('secondTimeMin'));
  var sec2 = Number(document.getElementById('secondTimeSec'));
  var min3 = Number(document.getElementById('thirdTimeMin'));
  var sec3 = Number(document.getElementById('thirdTimeSec'));

  var entryMin = Number(prompt('What is the time in minutes ?'));
  var newTimeMin = entryMin;
  var entrySec = Number(prompt('What is the time in seconds'));
  var newTimeSec = entrySec;

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (entryMin > min1 && entrySec > sec1) {
      document.getElementById('firstTimeMin').innerHTML = newTimeMin;
      document.getElementById('firstTimeSec').innerHTML = newTimeSec;
      break;
    } else if (entryMin > min2 && entrySec > sec2) {
      document.getElementById('secondTimeMin').innerHTML = newTimeMin;
      document.getElementById('secondTimeSec').innerHTML = newTimeSec;
      break;
    } else if (entryMin > min3 && entrySec > sec3) {
      document.getElementById('thirdTimeMin').innerHTML = newTimeMin;
      document.getElementById('thirdTimeSec').innerHTML = newTimeSec;
      break;
    }
  };

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

table,
td {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table of best times</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/besttime.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <caption>The best times</caption>
        <tr>
          <td id="firstTimeMin">1</td>
          <td id="firstTimeSec">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="secondTimeMin">3</td>
          <td id="secondTimeSec">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="thirdTimeMin">5</td>
          <td id="thirdTimeSec">6</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <button onclick="timeEntry()">
  Enter a new time
 </button>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

My idea was to simply get the data already in the table using `Number` or `parseInt` to get the number value, but either way from the test I've been doing, when I try to get the element from html, it tells me that I get a number type but when I try to use it in an operation it returns NaN. Maybe I'm just stupid, but I've been reading and looking for a day for a way to get the data from the cells as numbers, but aside from `Number` or `parseInt` or using a form, I haven't seen a way to do this and it feels like the more I search the less I understand why it doesn't work.
Any help or clue on how to get this done, even it means start back from scratch would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you rewrite your post and use a Snippet?

Comment: Try `document.getElementById(yourID).textContent` as at the moment you are trying to create a Number from the DOM element and not its value.

Comment: Thank you @thanh trung, didn't know I could do that

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('firstTimeMin')` only get the DOM Element, you should do `document.getElementById('firstTimeMin').innerHTML` to get the content of the HTML so you'll be able to get the number using `parseInt()` or `Number`.

Do the same with every elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot @thanh trung, I knew it was something elementary but every explanation or doc that I saw seemed to imply that getting the object allowed me to get the actual content while using only ```document.getElementById``` or ```document.getElementsByClassName```

Comment: @Akoan I tried console.log on the variable `min1` it's not correct.